# ubuntu 16.04 installed on second physical drive

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, chmod

My system has two drives.  The first is 500GB SSD and the second is a 3TB physical drive.

For some reason, that I apparently missed, when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 it installed on the SSD just fine, but it is referring to it as `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda` as I would expect.

Likewise, `CHMOD` doesn't seem to have any effect on the bigger physical drive.  I presume it is because it sees it as some other drive type?

In addition, when I look at a directory listing of files and folders on the bigger physical drive, they are a different color and have a background highlighting, unlike the smaller SSD drive.

The bigger physical drive is auto-mounted as /media/vern/volume-label

Any thoughts on how to get this machine and drives to be more "normal"  ie: the SSD as `/dev/sda` and bigger physical drive as `/dev/sdb` with a normal `chmod` permission and directory look and feel?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my `FDISK -L` output.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B2C62E3A-13E3-4B7E-8388-E5ABE26E241A

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 5860532223 5860268032  2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 12FE9AE6-010F-41D8-9E70-5825EB807C20

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1050624 909897727 908847104 433.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  909897728 976771071  66873344  31.9G Linux swap
```

Here is the output from `lsblk -f`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL        UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                                             
├─sdb2 ext4                549364ab-f1da-4499-8123-a5e01e32a6ae /
├─sdb3 swap                8eedb2cc-0eb9-4cf4-8dd5-44aa9c089c5d [SWAP]
└─sdb1 vfat                6068-BBAA                            /boot/efi
sr0                                                             
sda                                                             
├─sda2 ntfs   3TB-PHYSICAL 567ACCB07ACC8DE5 /media/vern/3TB-PHYSICAL
└─sda1
```

.

Comment: well .. I would probably install it again .. but leave the large drive disconnected so only the SSD is installed .. then after you have booted it once ... check it .. it should be sda .. then shutdown and add the large drive... it may not mount it automatically that way but it should show up as sdb .. you may have to mod the fstab to have it automount at boot though so it's a bit more work .. never actually tried this to see how it would react to adding a drive after the OS is installed .. but order doesn't really matter... my boot drive is located on sdd on my system.

Comment: as for CHMOD .. it wont work on the large drive at all nothing linux will .. you will see the files and be able to copy and do stuff but no permissions or owners because I think its an NTFS drive .. and permissions and owners don't work on NTFS .. it needs to be reformatted as ext3 or ext4 if you want to use linux permissions and ownership ..

Comment: if you look at `sudo lsblk -f` .. and look at the large drive .. does it say ntfs  or does it say ext3 or ext4

Comment: Good info about NTFS.   That's right, the bigger physical drive came from my previous Windoze 10 configuration.  WAY too much on there to reformat.  Oh my gosh that would be a nightmare of unequal levels.  LOL

As for the disconnecting and reinstalling... installing was a nightmare of its own with my video card GTX1060 not finding all five of my monitors etc.  I am hopeful to find another solution to that process.

Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: here is output from sudo lsblk -f

Comment: well shoot... it wouldn't let me post it.  I will see if I can edit the original post

Comment: then at this point I would leave it alone .. its perfectly fine to have it listed the way it is .. like I say mine is on sdd for my boot drive .. but .. if you can find another drive or buy another drive in the future ... you can just backup those files and then format the drive as ext4 and copy the files back ... no need to post it really .. we know now that its ntfs so that's your  issue with chmod

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is `/dev/sda1` assigned to the boot drive or the secondary drive.  That can change between reboots.  Or if you leave a USB drive in it can change too.  My home system boots my Ubuntu drive first with the grub on it, but is comes up a lot of the time at `/dev/sde`.  The main thing that I do is create mount points then assign the UUID's of the drives to the mount points.  You obtain those from running `sudo blkid`.

Comment: no problem glad we were able to clear it up for you :D

Answer (score 0):

the /dev devices are actually linked to physical devices so

`/dev/sda=sata port1
 /dev/sdb=sata port2
 ..`

the numbering starts from the first non empty port; so to have the ssd as sda instead of sdb you have to physicaly change its port in front of hdd

as noted in comments `chmod` works for linux type file systems; you could trick NTFS by editing `/etc/fstab` and adding `uid=xxx,gid=xxx,dmask=xxx,fmask=xxx` 
in the mount options; so every folder/files will have these attributes/id's

`uid=user id
gid=group id
dmask=directory mask
fmask=file mask`

see `man mount` or https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount for details

Comment: On my system SATA0 is first SATA port. And best to always use in order. If you have DVD make it last in drives used order. I have skipped ports and then on a re-boot with a flash drive all my devices get renumbered.  And if you have ASmedia ports do not use them.

Comment: @oldfred - for human logic makes sense 1=first for pc array logic 0=first is required; pls observe the bug when you physically connect device to port 10 but pc shows it as sdb having 9 empty physical slots from slot1(sda).. highly illogical for pc but easier??? for humans..

Comment: Where are you talking about changing the "port"?

Comment: @BigDaddyV - sata port1 = socket 1 and so on.. on the motherboard or you can switch between them the cables that link your sata devices with motherboard

Comment: This isn't always true.  It is the order it loads, yes, but it doesn't have to correspond to the port it is plugged into.  What happens when you have 6 ports on your system, but you hook your single drive up to the last SATA port and not the first one?  It comes up as `/dev/sda` and not as `/dev/sdf`.  Also, if you plug in a USB drive when it boots up, that will be loaded before the onboard SATAs are.  Then your letters have all shifted 1.  The USB will come up as `/dev/sda` but then your boot drive on SATA 6 will be `/dev/sdb`.